# Problems with theoremref

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I'm having some problems with the `theoremref` package. Basically, instead of giving me as output something like "Lemma 1.1.1", where "Lemma" is the name of the theorem, it gives me something like "lem 1.1.1", where "lem" is the theorem identifier. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theoremref}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{lem}\thlabel{test}
Test
\end{lem}

As we can see from \thref{test}

\end{document}
```

And here's the output:

[image: Output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: My suggestion is *not* to use `ntheorem`, but `amsthm`. In my opinion, `ntheorem` just *seems* better or more powerful, but it makes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`theoremref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/theoremref) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/theoremref/theoremref-doc.pdf) (section **4 Caveats**, p 3):

> The new referencing commands only work for theorem environments declared using
>   the `\newtheorem` command. You cannot use them for e. g. tables, figures, equations,
>   sections, and other environments.

So far so good... now, the [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) (section **3.2.2 `amsthm`**, p 16):

> `amsthm.sty` conflicts with the definition of theorem layouts in `theorem.sty`,
>   some features of `amsthm.sty` have been incorporated into option `[amsthm]`
>   which has to be used *instead* of `\usepackage{amsthm}`.
>   ...
>   The command `\newtheoremstyle` is not taken over from `amsmath.sty`. ...

The change of interface provided by [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) seem to make it incompatible with `theoremref` in this way. You need a little more fudging to make it work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsthm, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\let\old@thm\@thm
\usepackage{theoremref}
\def\@thm#1#2#3{\def\thmref@currname{#3}\old@thm{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{lem}\thlabel{test}
Test
\end{lem}

As we can see from \thref{test}

\end{document}
```

The above suggested solution stems from the compatibility of `theoremref` with [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), and the following lines in [`theoremref.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/theoremref/theoremref.sty) that captures the theorem type/name:

```
%hook in \@thm to get the name
\def\thmref@newthm#1#2{\thmref@lc{\def\thmref@currname{#2}}%
   \thmref@oldthm{#1}{#2}}
\def\thmref@amsthm#1#2#3{\thmref@lc{\def\thmref@currname{#3}}%
   \thmref@oldthm{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

Later on, depending on whether or not `amsmath` is loaded, a replacement is made:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\thmref@setup}
\def\thmref@setup{%
   \let\thmref@oldthm\@thm
   \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{\let\@thm\thmref@amsthm}%
        {\let\@thm\thmref@newthm}%
   \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
       \expandafter\let\csname thlabel\space\endcsname\thlabel@hyperref
       \let\thmref@setref\thmref@sethyp
   }\relax
   \ifx\thmref@th\@undefined\else\let\th\thmref@th\fi%
}
```

It may also be sufficient to fool that package in thinking `amsmath` is loaded (be setting `\ver@amsthm.sty` to anything other than `\relax`).

Answer (score 7):

There is some incompatibility between `ntheorem` and `theoremref`.

Since `ntheorem` defines its own `\thref` command when loaded with the `thref` option, I suggest you simply not to load `theoremref`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{theoremref}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{lem}\label{test}
Test
\end{lem}

As we can see from \thref{test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]